# Is it normal for websites to know my monitor resolution?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

With Javascript enabled in TBB, going to a [site to detect screen resolution](https://bestfirms.com/what-is-my-screen-resolution/) on Windows 7 gives my actual screen resolution. This is not just some fake value Tor Browser is giving, because it will be different if I change to a lower resolution in the display settings. Is this a bug? I would expect this value to be faked.

**Note:** I am not talking about the resolution of the browser window. I'm talking about the resolution of my entire monitor (1920x1080, in this case, is detected by the website above.)

Comment: If this is genuine it's a platform-specific issue, because on Linux it reports the size of the Tor Browser window (1000x958 on my widescreen monitor).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, but instead it is a part of how it was designed. We had a fairly lengthy discussion on whether or not we should force Tor Browser to "lie" about it's resolution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/bxf060/why_not_lie/):

To summarize:

> Websites get current window size via JavaScript. Everytime you load a
>   page or change the window size, the page can get this information.
>   This is not just for fingerprinting but also useful for layout,
>   formatting, responsiveness etc.. If Tor Browser lies about window
>   size, some pages may look awkward.
>
> Edit: It is not easy to lie about the resolution (whether via
>   JavaScript or CSS @media queries) and then get responsive webpages.

With that said, a design decision was made to keep the resolution at a standard so that way everyone who uses it will look the same to a web server that you are visiting.

Comment: I think you're talking about window resolution. I'm talking about screen resolution (my monitor resolution of 1920x1080, for example, is detected by the website). Screen resolution shouldn't be relevant to webpage layout. I'll edit the question to clarify this.